Difference-in-Differences when treatment predates time of implementation (t1)
I was wondering if you believed the difference-in-differences design I have in mind is appropriate given that the treatment pre-dates t1.
I want to estimate the effect of public libraries established between 1880 and 1920 on votes for populist parties. I have a county-level panel dataset of electoral results of my home country before and after EU ascension.
I ran TWFE models and found that counties with libraries score lower support for populist before and after EU ascension. However, the association is WAY stronger after EU ascension. I hypothesize that these libraries left behind strong social capital networks that undermine the appeal of populist platforms.
I am wondering whether I can use a DiD design even though the treatment technically precedes the time of implementation—ie. it is already present in t0. I already run the model and the parallel trend assumption holds plus the results align with my predictions.
I dither whether I should go forward with this design since I was always told that DiDs are better suited for “policy-like interventions.”
Best,

Is your treatment the establishment of public libraries, or the enlargement of the European Union?

My treatment is the establishment of public libraries.

If I understand you correctly, then treated counties always had public libraries. Is this correct?

Yes, that's correct.

Do you have a measure of how many libraries were erected in each year, something equating to a continuous treatment? And how did you test for parallel trends? What’s considering your pre-period?

My measure is binary: whether a public library was built at the county anytime between 1880 and 1920. I tested parallel trends visually and with did_check() function for the DIDdesign package on R My pre period is the 5 years before EU ascension. Thank you

I don’t mean to belabor this point, but if your treatment is the establishment of public libraries, then why are you assessing your outcome before and after EU ascension? Are you modeling EU ascension as well?

My argument is that the public libraries leave behind a legacy of cosmopolitan attitudes that are activated after EU ascension. After EU ascension, one of the main political cleavages in the country is cosmopolitanism vs. nationalism. Eurosceptic/populist parties tend to do worse in counties where there is a significant support for cosmopolitanism.

To sum up: the campaign to build public libraries in the late XIX century created a constituency for pro-EU parties in the early XXI century.
